# JSON or object when pass the data to scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I use the 'Postman' to fetch the data from API, it returns JSON format. Why I can either JSON or object to scope? Both JSON and object format is working. The difference between JSON and object (from my understanding) is that, JSON has double quote for key (for this example, "answers" has double quote), but object does not have double quote for key.

Here is the data returned from API:

```
 [
        {
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer": "Yes",
                    "count": 0,
                    "id": 1,
                    "question_id": 1
                },
                {
                    "answer": "No",
                    "count": 0,
                    "id": 2,
                    "question_id": 1
                }
            ],
            "id": 1,
            "question": "Is this hard?"
        },
   ...
]
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/AX051IiMsMD14AUBfMbr?p=preview) is the data passed to scope. You can see, both JSON ("answers") and object (answers) format are working.

**Updates: I want to know why API returns JSON data format, but we can pass JSON or object to scope? Which we should choose, JSON or object?**

Comment: so! what is the issue?

Comment: *"The difference between JSON and object...is that, JSON has double quote for key...but object does not have double quote for key."* - **No.** The difference is that JSON is a *string* format used for data transfer (that yes, does have double-quoted keys, but that's not the point), whereas a JS object *literal* is part of JS source code and can have double-quoted keys or not as the programmer sees fit.

Comment: @Sajeetharan I updated my questions.

Comment: To anyone who down vote my this post: May I know the reason? I use the code to ask which date format to use when pass data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are a little confused about what are JSON and Objects in Javascript

### JSON

JSON format is only for send data in a structured way, and it only can contain String, Bool, Number, Array, and another JSON inside (nested JSON)

### Object

In javascript objects have the same as JSON but with big different, that you can execute code Javascript inside them, so you can do it like so:

```
var object = {
 "hola": function(){
   console.log("This will work because this object can exec JS code")
 },
 age: 26,
 admin: false
}
```

Comment: "Maybe you are a little confused about what are JSON and Objects in Javascript". Yes. I am not sure what are they different indeed, so let me confuse when to use which one

Comment: don't worry, you have to use JSON when you need to send information to another server, because JSON was created to share information in a well-structured way, in the other hand you have objects in JS, you can use it almost for everything, when you are writing JS code, you can add function, to it, to then exec that function later, so you should know that JSON is only for sending information and literal objects in JS is for the same as JSON but  you can attach functionalities as well inside it

Comment: "you have to use JSON when you need to send info to another server" what do you mean another server? I think we only one server as server side, and one client side?

Comment: Yeah you have server side and client side, eg: you can send information to your API that it is hosted in the server side, so you can make an ajax call from client side to server side, generally the information is sent in JSON mode, and you can to send the same information from the server to another API (other server), the point is that if you want to send some information you should use JSON because it is easier to handle and read it.

Answer (score 0):

**JSON** is a standard of string representation of JavaScript objects (**J**avaScript **O**bject **N**otation). So they may logically represent the same information but are fundamentally different. You don't need to choose, you must send JSON (assume we are talking on HTTP level).

**Objects** conceptually can only live in the memory space and can have some piece of information that can't be easily serialized to textual content and don't have the corresponding JSON representation (references, bytes, ...)